# Camera not strafing (GLSL)

Tags: opengl, java, camera, libgdx, matrix

I use this code in my GLSL vertex shader, where `v_position` is the vertex position:

```
gl_Position = v_position * u_camera;
```

and set `u_camera` as follows:

```
meshShader.setUniformMatrix("u_camera", 
camera.view.mul(camera.projection).inv());
```

With the camera being an `PerspectiveCamera` of fov 45, width = aspect ratio and height = 1

This code is working when translating the camera over the z axis:

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
        camera.translate(0, 0, CAMERA_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
} else if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.S)) {
        camera.translate(0, 0, -CAMERA_SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}
```

But not when doing the same thing as above on the x axis, with the <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> keys.

The mesh (a triangle) looks like this before i press <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd>
(Translating with <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> is fine)

[image: Normal]

But when translating over the X axis it it looks like this:

[image: Wrong]

I don't know anything of matrix math, and I made this code experimenting with the various matrices of the `Camera` class

EDIT : This code  `camera.projection.mul(camera.view.inv())` does a similiar thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
meshShader.setUniformMatrix("u_camera", 
camera.view.mul(camera.projection).inv());
```

Well first of all, you're (probably, judging by the notation) inverting the view AND projection matrices. This isn't correct. The inversion is only a part of the creation of a view matrix.

Also, an orthographic camera doesn't have a FOV, so i'm not sure if you haven't gotten some things mixed up because of that as well.

Comment: So sorry it's a PerspectiveCamera

Comment: And, yes, I'm inverting the product of the two matrices.

Comment: Aside from that, gl_Position = v_position * u_camera; should be gl_Position = u_camera * v_position; since OpenGL uses column matrices. I'd recommend you to read the Matrices tutorial on http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

Comment: @sarahm No it doesn't, GLSL will use what ever multiplication is appropriate for the notation. If you'll write vector * matrix, then the vector will be treated as a row vector, if you'll write matrix * vector then the vector will be treated as a column vector. I do all my 3D calculations using row vectors, because it's more natural to write it like that for me. It's up to you to set up your matrices for row or column multiplication, OpenGL doesn't care.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I don't know a thing about vector math; calculating the matrix that way works fine (the camera rotates and translates nicely). When I'll understand matrix math maybe I'll rewrite this code.

Comment: @TM3P I was talking to sarahm, his comment is incorrect, i have no idea why it has 2 upvotes. It applies to your situation because that's how your matrices are constructed, but it's not a rule. It's alright if you don't understand this at all, but he should if he's commenting on it. BTW, if you'd like to learn linear algebra in a very accessible manner, try Game Engine Architecture by Jason Gregory, the information is presented in a VERY accessible manner and it's by a game developer for game developers.

Comment: @dreta Point 9.005 of the opengl faq says you're right: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm